# Stripe Charge Connected Account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm running Rails 4 and am trying to create a payout system with Stripe. I have set up connect managed accounts for my users and would now like to have them, in order to register, subscribe to a yearly fee.

Must I create a separate customer and set up the subscription separately from the connect managed account? Or can I create a subscription for the managed account directly?

EDIT:

To clarify: must I create a separate customer for each user in order to process his subscription, or can I do that through his connect managed account?

Answer (score 0):

You need a seperate stripe account for api key and application settings. In this account you will get all your customer and payment/ subscription related information.

Comment: Can I not use the same API key & account?

Comment: Do you mean that API settings account and customer account same?

Comment: Yes it's possible to use same account for application settings and subscription.